# Pre-requisites in web deploy of win app

Tags: clickonce, prerequisites, web-deployment-project

I have a win form application that is deployed through a web site using the one click.

In the publish tab of the properties of the project, i click the Prerequisites button to add .Net 2.0 and Installer 3.1 and nothing else. I publish my app.

When clients go to run the app from the web site using the launch (as the run doesn't work), they get an error that a prerequiste is missing, SqlCE 3.5, but it is not even selected in the publish tab.

What do i have to do to remove SqlCE from the prerequisites?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check your project and see if there are any references to SQLCE.

If you need to use a SQLCE database, you can deploy the dll's locally instead of installing it as a prerequisite.

RobinDotNet